# Problem printing values within nested dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have two nested dictionaries inside the DEFAULTS dictionary: one is called PASSWRD and it has pairs depicting specific messages and another called COMMANDS, listing the commands I wish to use in my program, and a brief description of some key-pairs. One of those key-pairs is "Password", to which it is assigned a number.

Now, I am trying to go through a small loop that matches the "Password" key-pair value to one on PASSWRD.

When I try:

```
for command, stuff in DEFAULTS["COMMANDS"].items():
    print(f"\nCommand: {command}")
    print(f'{stuff["Definition"]}')
```

it lists all the commands and Definitions nicely. Problem start when I add the following line:

```
    print(f'{stuff["Password"]}')
```

it delivers the following error message: `KeyError: 'Password'`

Any ideas why this error is produced?

The final idea would be to produce something like this:

```
print(DEFAULTS["PASSWRD"][DEFAULTS["COMMANDS"][{stuff}]["Password"]])
```

which does not work. However,

```
print(DEFAULTS["PASSWRD"][DEFAULTS["COMMANDS"]["ZV"]["Password"]])
```

works nicely

You can find the MWE below.

```
DEFAULTS = {
        "PASSWRD" : {
        0 : "None",
        1: "Requires standard password",
        2: "Requires factory password",
                },
        "COMMANDS" : {
        "ZS" : {
                "Type" : "SETUP",
                "Max Parameters Required" : 1,
                "Parameters" : "[,n]",
                "Definition" : "Set/Get Seeder delay",
                "Password": 0 
                },
        "ZV" : {
                "Type" : "SETUP",
                "Max Parameters Required" : 1,
                "Parameters" : "[,n]",
                "Definition" : "Set/Get Variable Sync delay",
                "Password": 0 
                },
                }                 
        }


for command, stuff in DEFAULTS["COMMANDS"].items():
    print(f"\nCommand: {command}")
    print(f'{stuff["Definition"]}')
#   print(f'{stuff["Password"]}')
    print(DEFAULTS["PASSWRD"][DEFAULTS["COMMANDS"]["QD"]["Password"]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`stuff` is the current dictionary in the `COMMANDS` iteration, it's not a key of anything. So use `stuff["Password"]` to get the Password from that dictionary.

```
for command, stuff in DEFAULTS["COMMANDS"].items():
    print(f"\nCommand: {command}")
    print(f'{stuff["Definition"]}')
    print(DEFAULTS["PASSWRD"][stuff["Password"]])
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/qTWlBQ)

Comment: In this case, why doesn't the commented out print statement work?

Comment: Also, the code you posted - print(DEFAULTS["PASSWRD"][stuff["Password"]])  - doesn't work - it states 'KeyError: 'Password'"

Comment: It works fine for me.

Comment: Are you using Python 3.6?

Comment: I'm using 3.9.2. But there's nothing here that would be version-dependent.

Comment: I just ran a clean version of the MWE and your code indeed works. I need to check my code more thoroughly. I will mark this question as answered. Thanks again!